# Center align content in small screens

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

I'm New in bootstrap 4.
trying to create a grid system that has left aligned content in wider screens and centered content in smaller screen.

I have this snippet :
https://www.codeply.com/go/NnGivBjnBd

I'm able to align to the  center by adding class="row justify-content-center" to the "row" div.
However , I did not manage to  make it left aligned only for lg break point.
Any ideas ?
Thanks
Sagi

Answer (score 6):

Use these classes: `justify-content-center` and `justify-content-md-start`.

These will make the row centered, but align it to left at the `md` size and up.